# reload the page on button click based on button properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

Some context. I've added inside Page_Load of a class Method1 that generates a repeater and Method2 that generates an array of buttons.
Each button is attached dynamically an event inside Method2.
The buttons will never change, but based on clicking a button the repeated elements should change.

My main problem is/are:
1) when I click a button, the event causes the page to load (Page_Load) which calls Method1, which generates the default repeater, instead of the one associated with my specific event attached to button x from the array of buttons;  --> so, I wrapped up Method1 in !isPostBack ... then, nothing happens at all

How would you avoid this? What principles would you use for implementig this?

Attempted so far:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(!IsPostBack)
                {
                    GetItems(1, 2); //default values (first time the page is loaded)
                    GenerateButtons(10);
                }
            }

 private void GenerateButtons(int c)
        {
            LinkButton[] x = new LinkButton[c];

            for(int i=0; i<c;i++)
            {
                x[i] = new LinkButton();
                x[i].Text = (i+1).ToString();
                Panel1.Controls.Add(x[i]);

                x[i].OnClientClick += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

            }
        }
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;  // Which button was clicked;

            GetItems(int.Parse(button.Text)-1, 3); //3 is a constant; first argument is index of button extracted from its caption

        }
```

//clicking a button should load the page invoking GetItems() specific to the button pressed (first argument is its index) and should regenerate the buttons, maybe highlighting in some way the one that was previously pressed.
To help performance, it would also help not to regenerate the buttons after a page was first loaded.

I'm working with ASP.NET and C#.

My main problem is Button_Click is never invoked, probably because the buttons are regenerated when clicking a button so their definitions is recreated, including the buttons' events.

Comment: Your `Button_Click` event would always be fired *before* the regeneration, anyway; so this is not the problem. Your problem, however, *might* lie in your `x[i].OnClientClick += ...` code? Without looking (and a long time out of practice with classic ASP), don't you need to hook up `OnClick`, rather than `OnClientClick` event?

Comment: Geoff, thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, I am using LinkButtons, which don't have onClick method.

Comment: No problem. Always worth trying to help. A little bit of Googling (other search engines are available) led me to find a `.Click` event? Don't want to appear to be clutching at straws. Case in point is that you need to get the correct click handler working for your delegate method to be called :)

Comment: This is marvellous. Can't believe it was that. Thank you very much Geoff. If you'd like to add this as an answer, I will mark it. Have a great day!!

Comment: My pleasure. Always the simple little things that catch us out! Happy programming! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Button_Click` handler would *always* be fired *before* the regeneration, anyway; so this is not the problem.

Your problem, however, lies in your `x[i].OnClientClick += ...` code.

You need to hook up to the `.Click` event of the `LinkButton` to listen to the right event.

Like this:

```
private void GenerateButtons(int c)
{
    LinkButton[] x = new LinkButton[c];

    for(int i=0; i<c;i++)
    {
        x[i] = new LinkButton();
        x[i].Text = (i+1).ToString();
        Panel1.Controls.Add(x[i]);

        x[i].Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click); // Use the 'Click' event

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!